# Problem to connect angular app and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript

i want to connect two app ,one created in react an the second in angular.Angular app is a login component and the react is a list of products.I imported a script tag in html document in angular app but I dont render a component in a dom.Product List is empty(not rendered)I have some error in console

```js
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #200; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=200 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Object.t.render (react-dom.production.min.js:296:48)
    at index.js:7:1
    at index.js:17:1
```

```js
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import {
  AngularBroadcastService,
  EventKeys,
} from './services/broadcast.service';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { ScriptLoaderService } from './services/ScriptLoaderServices';

import { MicroEventBus } from 'MicroFrontEnd';
export let microEventBus: MicroEventBus = (window as any).microEventBus;

declare let Vue: any;
declare let ShoppingCartVue: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-app';
  hideProducts: boolean = false;
  hideShoppingCart: boolean = true;
  hideOrderPlaced: boolean = true;
  hideShoppingCartRegion: boolean = false;
  username: string = '';

  shoppingCartStyles = 'split right';

  @ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav: MatSidenav | null = null;

  constructor(
    AngularBroadCastService: AngularBroadcastService,
    private scriptLoaderService: ScriptLoaderService,
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
    _.bindAll(this, [
      'onLoginClicked',
      'onLoginEvent',
      'toggleCheckoutOnly',
      'toggleContinueShopping',
      'togglePlaceOrder',
    ]);
    AngularBroadCastService.on(EventKeys.LOGIN_BUTTON_CLICKED).subscribe(
      this.onLoginClicked
    );
    AngularBroadCastService.on(EventKeys.USER_LOGIN_EVENT).subscribe(
      this.onLoginEvent
    );

    microEventBus.on('checking-out').subscribe(this.toggleCheckoutOnly);

    microEventBus
      .on('continue-shopping')
      .subscribe(this.toggleContinueShopping);

    microEventBus.on('place-order').subscribe(this.togglePlaceOrder);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // createReactApp();
    this.scriptLoaderService
      .loadAllScripts('/assets/main.613915a5.js','/asset/787.43ba7358.chunk.js')
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log(`script loaded`);
      });
    Vue.createApp(ShoppingCartVue).mount('#vue-application');
  }

  onLoginClicked(event: string) {
    console.log(`AppComponent received : ${event}`);

    this.sidenav?.open();
  }
  onLoginEvent(username: string) {
    this.sidenav?.close();
    this.hideShoppingCart = false;
    this.username = username;
  }

  toggleCheckoutOnly() {
    this.shoppingCartStyles = 'split';
    this.hideProducts = true;
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }

  toggleContinueShopping() {
    this.shoppingCartStyles = 'split right';
    this.hideProducts = false;
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }
  togglePlaceOrder() {
    this.hideShoppingCartRegion = true;
    this.hideProducts = true;
    this.hideOrderPlaced = false;
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

```js
<app-header></app-header>

<mat-sidenav-container class="full-height-container">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="over" class="content-padding" [fixedInViewport]="true" [fixedTopGap]="60" [fixedBottomGap]="0" [opened]="false">
        <app-login></app-login>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <div class="content-padding">
            <div [hidden]="hideProducts" class="split left">
                <h2>Product List</h2>
                <div id="root"></div>
            </div>

            <div [hidden]="hideShoppingCartRegion" class="{{ shoppingCartStyles }}">
                <h2>Shopping Cart</h2>
                <p *ngIf="hideShoppingCart">Please login to view your shopping cart</p>
                <div [hidden]="hideShoppingCart" id="vue-application"></div>
            </div>
            <div [hidden]="hideOrderPlaced" class="split left">
                <h2>Order Placed</h2>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>Thank you, {{ username }}.</p>
                <p>Your order has been placed.</p>
                <p>- The Switch Sales team.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <script src="/assets/MicroEventBus.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/main.613915a5.js"></script>
    <link href="/assets/main.ca0fa319.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta name=" viewport " content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 " />
    <link rel="icon " type="image/x-icon " href="favicon.ico " />
    <link rel="preconnect " href="https://fonts.gstatic.com " />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap " rel="stylesheet " />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons " rel="stylesheet " />
</head>

<body class="mat-typography">
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

This is how I expected to see:

[image]

Comment: `I imported a script tag in html document in angular app but I dont render a component in a dom`.  Could you please elaborate this?

Comment: I'm trying to render list of products that I created in react in angular project which is a login form and shopping cart. I have some book example where it said that I need to import script tag of my react project to angular. I do that but I don' get it. I try to find some example how to connect this two but I'cant.

Comment: Got it. It could be a lot of things. The error you had was this: [https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=200](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=200), which points to `Target container is not a DOM element.`. You can try doing more of your research using this phrase.